# SASS with Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sass

yesterday I`ve got problems with HAML and Rails 3 which resolved themself.

Today i wanted to try SASS and its not working. I have renamed my files to file.scss. The GemFile is up to date with `gem "haml"`. There comes an error, because Rails can`t render my css files.

Has anyone some ideas to solve this problem?

Peter

Answer (score 5):

Rename your file with the .sass extention and put them in a /public/stylesheets/sass directory.

Comment: Hey Yannis, 

this doesn`t work.
I have renamed the files to filename.sass and shifted them into public/stylesheets/sass/

Comment: Try to load the corresponding /stylesheets/filename.css file and check if you get any error logged in

Comment: in my haml file i have the entry 

%link{:href => "/stylesheets/default.sass", :rel => "stylesheet"}


and in my console there is no error:

Comment: Ah! You need something like a `= stylesheet_link_tag 'filename'` link in your haml file. This is a link to the css file. Try to load /stylesheets/filename.css in your browser to verify that you don't get any error.

Comment: ok, i have changed the line in my haml file like

= stylesheet_link_tag 'default' 
( my file has the name default.css )
and now its working!

Thx for your help

Comment: @Peter: You see that big check mark next to Yannis' answer? Click it.